# Control of 230 V submersible pump and pressure switch via two float switches and relay

Tags: relay

I have a spring fed water well at the same height as my house and I'm installing a large potable water storage tank on higher ground 15 m above and 50 m distant.
Pump - 230 V Diver 6-850 MA and Grundfos PM2 96848738 + one float switch situated in spring fed water well, second float switch in storage tank 50 m away.

The water well dries up periodically so float switch - closed in buoyant position -  is to prevent extraction once the flow fails and level drops. Float switch in top storage tank to prevent overfilling - so normally open in buoyant position.

Please can you suggest best circuit / components, SSR / EMR to avoid relay chatter as levels alter.

Can we stick with mains voltage to control relay or is low voltage preferable (apart from safety concerns)?

Apologies for lack of detail in post;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbzsQs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I've flagged this for migration to DIY. Please note that shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Transistor - Shopping questions / recommendations are [off-topic at DIY.SE too](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Mods are told not to migrate questions which are off-topic on the target site, so I'm unable to migrate the question.

Comment: Link the float switch and state the current it will switch please.

Comment: Choe, I'm not at all complaining, and I know you are trying to write something short and direct, but you haven't really given us a good description. Provide more detail and the sensors you have and the difficulties. I do get the idea you may need some hysteresis in your system. But I really don't understand all of the edge cases, yet. More would help a lot

Comment: Jonk, Andy, sorry about the lack of information, trying to use the schematic drawing package but struggling ! will get there and re -submit my problem. Thank you for looking

Comment: @Choe You will need to use an @-sign in front of our names when writing to us. You are allowed to do that for exactly one person, though. So you'll have to choose. I just dropped by but had not received any notification that you had written anything. So time went by. Sorry about that.